# consumeAsync Return Error Code 5: Developer Error

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

***Edited with more information.***

I am getting error code 5 which I believe is 'Developer Error'. The mDebugMessage in the BillingResult is `Invalid Token`. (I have checked the name and I am sure it is correct.)

I am calling `consumeAsync("noadverts");` where `"noadverts"` is the name of my in app product.

When I check my purchases, it records the following:

```
{"orderId":"GPA.1111-1111-1111-1111",
"packageName":"myname.com.myname",
"productId":"noadverts",
"purchaseTime":1565188785096,
"purchaseState":0,
"purchaseToken":"edited for length",
"acknowledged":true}
```

Unusually, when I call:

```
int val1 = purchase.getPurchaseState();
```

then `val1` is `1` and not `0` as it suggested in the purchase JSON.

I am using much of the TestDrive example, but without the `BillingUpdatesListener`.

```
 public void consumeAsync(final String purchaseToken) {
    // If we've already scheduled to consume this token - no action is needed (this could happen
    // if you received the token when querying purchases inside onReceive() and later from
    // onActivityResult()
    if (mTokensToBeConsumed == null) {
        mTokensToBeConsumed = new HashSet<>();
    } else if (mTokensToBeConsumed.contains(purchaseToken)) {
        //Log.i(TAG, "Token was already scheduled to be consumed - skipping...");
        return;
    }
    mTokensToBeConsumed.add(purchaseToken);

    // Generating Consume Response listener
    final ConsumeResponseListener onConsumeListener = new ConsumeResponseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onConsumeResponse(BillingResult response, String purchaseToken) {
            @BillingClient.BillingResponseCode int responseCode = response.getResponseCode();

            // THIS IS WHERE I GET ERROR CODE 5
        }
    };

    // Creating a runnable from the request to use it inside our connection retry policy below
    Runnable consumeRequest = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Consume the purchase async
            //mBillingClient.consumeAsync(purchaseToken, onConsumeListener);

            ConsumeParams consumeParams = ConsumeParams.newBuilder().setPurchaseToken(purchaseToken).build();
            // Consume the purchase async
            mBillingClient.consumeAsync(consumeParams, onConsumeListener);
        }
    };

    executeServiceRequest(consumeRequest);
}
```

Any ideas what might be the issue?

If I try and purchase `"noadverts"` again I get the error code `Item is already owned.`